# Using maatwebsite excel with userfrosting

Tags: php, excel, userfrosting

I am trying to do an export of custom data which gets fed into DataTables in userfrosting. I have loaded the maatwebsite excel library using composer and the autoload_classmap.php was updated.
In the controller I tried using the following:

```
Excel::create('master',function($excel) use($events){                    
    $excel->sheet('Master List', function($sheet) use($events){          
        $sheet->fromArray($events);                                      
    });                                                                  
})->export('xls');
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'UserFrosting\Excel' not found in /usr/www
```

I have looked at the laravel examples and tried them and they work with no problems. But I need this to work on userfrosting as the application is already and only missing the export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up leaving `maatwebsite/excel` for `phpoffice/phpexcel` which worked a bit quicker for me, I will attempt to get an answer to this question in the near future.

Comment: Thanks for the update! You saved my day. Kindly update this page info, if you were able to have maatwebsite/excel running in UF and if you found it more useful than phpexcel. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please see feedback I received from the maatwebsite forum, they say they only assist if you have issues on laravel as it is its main support. 
https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/866

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a namespace issue.  Try:

```
\Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create(...
```

Note that I've used the fully qualified namespace for the [`Excel`](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/2.1/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/Excel.php) class.

Comment: Hi @alexw , thanks for the response, I am still getting the same result `Class 'Maatwebsite\Excel' not found` when I implement `use \Maatwebsite\Excel\Files\NewExcelFile as Excel;` I am starting to feel like I might not know what I am doing here.

Comment: Can you post the full set of changes that you've made to your controller file?

Comment: My code
`namespace UserFrosting;
use \Maatwebsite\Excel\Files\NewExcelFile as Excel;

class MyController extends \UserFrosting\BaseController {
     public function pageMaster()
    {
         $events = Events::get();
         Excel::create('master',function($excel) use($events){                    
            $excel->sheet('Master List', function($sheet) use($events){          
                $sheet->fromArray($events);                                      
            });                                                                  
        })->export('xls');
    }
}
`

Comment: Also, I just updated my answer.  Get rid of your `use` statement, and just try my code with the fully qualified path.

Comment: I have crated the gist with the new error I am encountering here:
https://gist.github.com/TheMainJoe/ad7271ce3cd9822c1e4667a390eab09b

Comment: Perhaps we should continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.userfrosting.com/).